# MySQL friendship schema

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

```
create table users
(
    id_user int(9) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    email varchar(64)
);

create table friendships
(
    id_friendship int(9) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    id_friend1 int(9),
    id_friend2 int(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_friend1) REFERENCES users(id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_friend2) REFERENCES users(id_user),
    UNIQUE(id_friend1,id_friend2)
)
```

I want to avoid have the same friendship between two users twice.
But I still can insert the same friendship twice like this:

```
INSERT INTO friendships( id_friend1, id_friend2) VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO friendships( id_friend1, id_friend2) VALUES (2,1)
```

To me (1,2) and (2,1) are equals and I want to avoid it. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I would reverse the logic. When you insert one, ALWAYS insert the other. Have a little flag identifying the 'true' one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write those ids in a certain order. For example, before inserting, try to make sure that the smaller id goes into the left column and the bigger id into the other column.

In your example will be always like:

```
INSERT INTO friendships( id_friend1, id_friend2) VALUES (1,2)
```

and never something like:

```
INSERT INTO friendships( id_friend1, id_friend2) VALUES (2,1)
```

Since id 2 is bigger than id 1.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not sure if this is legal, but maybe you could expand this thought in to something like `INSERT INTO friendships( id_friend1, id_friend2) VALUES ( LEAST(a,b), GREATEST(a,b) )`?

Comment: This ignores the concept of reciprocation - i.e. who initiated and who reciprocated the friendship - which can be important.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySql still does not support the check constraint, so you have to enforce this restriction in your business logic. If you want to insert (1,2), just simply check if (2,1) exists by running a simple select statement.